# \setbeamertemplate{headline} unexpected behavior when in preamble

Tags: beamer, templates

I was creating my own beamer template when I encountered some strange behavior. I have two headline templates, one for title slides and one for regular slides, and the two headlines involve `beamercolorbox`es with different heights and depths. But when I set the "regular" template in the preamble, I get some strange behavior.

I've created a MWE to recreate the issue. Hopefully I haven't changed the context of the problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate{headline}{title}{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=1cm, dp=1cm]{title in head/foot}
\Large title headline
\end{beamercolorbox}
}

\defbeamertemplate{headline}{body}{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}{title in head/foot}
\Large body headline
\end{beamercolorbox}
}

% With no \setbeamertemplate in the header, everything behaves as expected.

% Almost correct, footline appears on second slide
%\setbeamertemplate{headline}[body]

% First slide has footline, second slide has extra vertical padding
%\setbeamertemplate{headline}[title]

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}[title]
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\frame{}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}[body]
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\frame{}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output (from left to right) depending on if nothing is uncommented, if `\setbeamertemplate{headline}[body]` is uncommented, or if`\setbeamertemplate{headline}[title]` is uncommented:
[image: Screenshot of the output for the three described versions: no setbeamertemplate in preamble, set title template, set body template]
Can anyone say where either I or beamer went wrong? I'm using `beamer 2021/03/19 v3.62`.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you get and add which beamer version you use? (I don't get a footline on any of the slides --  as expected, but headlines of different heights need beamer version 3.70 or newer)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I've added screenshots and the version (3.62) which is less than 3.70. Is that the reason, then?

Comment: Yes! In versions prior to 3.70, the frame geometry was only calculated once at the start of the document. Now it is calculated at the start of each frame, which allows to have headlines of different height.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess it's time for me to update my distribution ^^

Comment: Good idea :) :)